# How do I only display part of a string using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I want to be able to display a string of characters up to 10 characters. If the string goes over 10 characters, I'd like to append '...' to the end.

For example, if I have the string:

```
'helloworldmynameisryan'
```

I want it to be displayed like so:

```
'helloworld...'
```

I'm just displaying my string in a div like this:

```
<div>DisplayMessage</div>
```

Is there a class that I could create that would only apply if the string were over 10 char?

Comment: An exact character count is difficult/impossible, but you can certainly restrict it to a width: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124838/how-to-keep-div-on-one-line-and-append-ellipses/15124873#15124873

Comment: Character counts wont work with CSS. As Tim mentioned, your solution would have to be width based. Here's a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8atfj/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good cross browser way to do this using only CSS. 'text-overflow' relies on the width of the string, and not the length of string as you need.

You can use the .length property of strings in javascript to achieve this

```
function ellipsify (str) {
    if (str.length > 10) {
        return (str.substring(0, 10) + "...");
    }
    else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Firefox does in fact now support this, you just need to ensure that whatever you are trying to 'truncate' has block level formatting and a width - which could be the parent.

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display:block;
    width : 100px; /* this could be defined on any parent */
}
```

Comment: Why would 100px correspond to 10 characters displayed, except by accident?

Comment: Looks better, clean and fast than javascript solution.

Answer (score 4):

Without using any `serverside` script or `javascript` you can not do this.

Use below function.

```
function LimitCharacter($data,$limit = 20)
{
    if (strlen($data) > $limit)
    {
        $data = substr($data, 0, strrpos(substr($data, 0, $limit), ' ')) . '...';
        return $data;
    }
    else
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

call it as `LimitCharacter($yourString,5);`

**Javascript**

```
var str = 'Some very long string';
if(str.length > 10) str = str.substring(0,10)+"...";
```

**CSS**

```
.limtiCharClass {
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* Opera */
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;   /* IE, Safari (WebKit) */
    overflow:hidden;              /* don't show excess chars */
    white-space:nowrap;           /* force single line */
    width: 300px;                 /* fixed width */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it´s called ellipsis and you can use it on a block element.

However it does not work in Firefox and you cannot set the width to exactly 10 characters as you cannot specify the width in characters in css.

If you want exactly 10 characters and Firefox compatibility you will have to use javascript or a server-side solution.

check ellipsis:http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

or try this:

```
.ellipsis{
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.ellipsis:after{
  content:'...';
}
```

jQuery plugin for this:

http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The ellipses is a css3 function and when testing in different browsers it has issues. A quick get around would be to define a specific with to the div or span with overflow hidden and then add a background images which says "..."

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

in your css

This will restrict your text to the width of the container. If the text exceeds the width, it will instead be displayed with an ellipsis (...).

This may help:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Answer (score -1):

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html), if there is a long text like

```
 <div>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
```

To wrap this you have many ways, use `<wbr>` tag like below

```
 <div>111111111111111111111111111<wbr>11111111111111111111111111111</div>
```

It will be displayed like
     1111111111111111111111
     1111111111111111111111
or use `&shy;` instead of , output will be

```
 111111111111111111111-
 1111111111111111111111
```

Or if you are looking for JS solution, then use [this](https://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

Comment: The question was about truncation, not wrapping.